# open a specific sheet when I open my excel file

Tags: excel, automation, tableofcontents

I have a file with a table of contents in the first sheet, is there a way to open the first sheet automatically even if for example I made changes in the third sheet, saved, exit, and opened the file again?

Comment: Are you manipulating the file with code? what set of tools are you using? Have you tried setting the `ActiveSheet` before you save?

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, go to your workbook's VBA project and double click "This Workbook". Then, in the code window paste in the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The Sheet you want").Activate
End Sub
```

Obviously, replace `The Sheet you want` with the name of the sheet you want to select.

Also note that then you have to save the workbook as macro-enabled.

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: it wants the file to be a macro-enabled file type, any chance to do it with .xlsx file? maybe using PERSONAL.XLSB ?

Comment: No - See my second-to-last line. The moment you use VBA (and you need to), it has to become macro-enabled

Comment: It makes sense obviously. I personally use macros with xlsx files using personal workbook (PERSONAL.XLSB), but i will try your way :) i will also look at all differences of xlsx and xlsm files if there are any except the macros